# Selenium webdriver with Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What are the advantages of using visual studio with selenium web driver compared to selenium web driver with eclipse?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter.

If you design a framework plan of extending it towards Jenkins,I would suggest the C# based code as it has the control over nunit,visual studio tests.

If you have plans to expand across testng,cucumber and maven or ant then I would suggest Java based framework.

Comment: Thanks...This would help.